# Annotate Faceted GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, facet

sample code

```
library(ggplot2)

# Base Plot
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) + 
  theme_bw()  # apply bw theme

g + facet_wrap( ~ class, scales = "free") + labs(title="hwy vs displ", caption = "Source: mpg", subtitle="Ggplot2 - Faceting - Multiple plots in one figure with free scales")
```

desired output
[image]

My objective is to add text 'Group A' and 'Group B' to specified rows in a faceted GGPlot. I have seen how to do this inside of each plot but is it possible to annotate on the outside as in the graphic example above?

Answer (score 0):

Using package `ggpubr`:

```
library(ggpubr)

# Simulating groups
mpg$Group <- "A"
mpg[mpg$class %in% unique(mpg$class)[1:3], "Group"] <- "B"


# Generating plots by group
for (grp in unique(mpg$Group)) {
  assign(paste0("plot", grp),
    ggplot(subset(mpg, Group == grp), aes(displ, hwy)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
      scale_y_continuous(position = "righ") +
      theme_bw() +
      facet_wrap(~ class, nrow = 1, scales = "free")
  )
}

# Arranging plots with annotation
ggarrange(annotate_figure(plotA, left = "Group A"),
          annotate_figure(plotB, left = "Group B"),
          nrow = 2, align = "h")
```

[image]

Also check the option `labels = "AUTO"` in ggarrange.